# Visio - define style for specific shape type

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

My use of Visio 2016 has been revolutionized by discovery of adding "Define Style" to my ribbon. I would like to set some specific text styling for a specific shape type. For example, I want all off-page reference shapes to have Arial 10 point bold text.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here is to copy the shape into a new stencil, edit the shape text format to be how you want it, save the new stencil and only use this version for the future.